# Chef notifies in same resource block as only_if or not_if

Tags: chef-infra

If I have a *notifies* in the same block as an *only_if*, will the *only_if* (if it evaluates to false) prevent the notification?  Can't seem to find any examples either way.

In debugging, it seems like the notification occurs anyway, and the only way to get the desired behavior is to place another *only_if* in the block that receives the notification.

An example would be copying an rc.local file and running it only for certain servers, but keeping the execute block generic so it can be called for any server:

```
cookbook_file '/etc/rc.d/rc.local' do
  source 'rc.local.servername'
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  mode '0744'
  action :create
  only_if { node.name =~ /servername/ }
  notifies :run, 'execute[run_rc_local]'
end

execute 'run_rc_local' do
  command '/etc/rc.local'
  user  'root'
  group 'root'
  action :nothing
end
```

In this case, it seems like the execute block gets notified even if the *only_if* evaluates to false.  Just can't find any documentation that states that explicitly.

Here is what the output looks like...  In the middle of the run, we see this:

```
  * cookbook_file[/etc/rc.d/rc.local] action create (skipped due to only_if)
  * execute[run_rc_local] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
```

But then at the bottom, where deferred actions take place, there is this:

```
 * execute[run_rc_local] action run
```

And yes, we searched through all the cookbooks and made sure that the execute block is not notified by anything else.

Comment: Can you show the output (update the question) of `chef-client` run that shows that the `execute` block got notified?

Comment: Outputs added to original question.  We've done some more testing and are pretty confident this is the way it works -- The notify fires even if the block is not run due to an only_if statement.  If would just be nice to see that spelled out in the Chef docs.

Comment: That's strange because `notifies` only applies when the "state changes". I am using `chef-client 16.2.73`, and I am not seeing this behaviour. The "notified" resource is *not running* when (i) `node.name` does not match (ii) file is `(up to date)`.